# Fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_log-vc141-mt-gd-1_64.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2017, lib

I'm writing a program which utilizes Boost logging features and consequently, when attempting to build the said program, I'm getting the following error when generating code (on Visual Studio 2017):

> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_log-vc141-mt-gd-1_64.lib'

However, I can confirm the following:

- boost_1_64_0\stage\lib has been added to "Additional Library Directories" under Linker -> General
- libboost_log-vc141-mt-gd-1_64.lib is located under stage/lib since when unpacking Boost, I did a complete build with toolset set to 14.1
- following relevant question's answers, I did add the specific .lib to "Additional Dependencies" under Linker -> Input

I feel like it's something obvious that I am missing. But, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you mixing 32 and 64 bit?

Comment: Set the `Tools->Options`, `Projects and Solutions->Build and Run`, `MSBuild project build log verbosity` to `Diagnostic`. Build your project. Examine the log in your intermediate output folder and search for the boost library name and the link command line it uses.

Comment: building knight online sources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[drescherjm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487892/drescherjm) was correct, I was mixing 32 and 64 bit. Needed to change Target Machine under Project Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Advanced to **MACHINEX86** and it worked.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was using the below define for linking log libraries in order to use dynamically. I removed it and worked.

```
//#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK 1 // necessary when linking the boost_log library dynamically
```