# LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_log-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib'?

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2019

I am getting this error .I managed to find similar question on stackoverflow [Fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_log-vc141-mt-gd-1_64.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333290/fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-libboost-log-vc141-mt-gd-1-64-lib).

I tried to follow the same steps in visual studio 2019.But I could not figure out how to remove this error .
I have done `right click on project name-> properties->linker->general->Additional Library Directories->packages\boost.1.72.0.0\lib\native\include` .

Packages are installed in NuGet using the “Install-Package” command.

```
PM> Install-Package boost
PM> Install-Package boost_date_time-vc141
PM> Install-Package boost_filesystem-vc141
PM> Install-Package boost_log-vc141
PM> Install-Package boost_system-vc141
PM> Install-Package boost_thread-vc141
PM> Install-Package boost_chrono-vc141
PM> Install-Package boost_log_setup-vc141
PM> Install-Package boost_chrono-vc141
PM> Install-Package boost_atomic-vc141
```

Please someone who can solve this is issue please answer my question.

Comment: The folder you added is an *include* folder, not the folder containing the *library*.

Comment: in the include folder there is boost directory

Comment: Do you mean a boost library?

Comment: @OfekShilon its like this `packages\boost.1.72.0.0\lib\native\include\boost`

Comment: You need to add the directory to the setting that contains the file `libboost_log-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib`. presumably you also need to install the `boost_log-vc142` nuget package

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have installed `boost_log-vc142 ` and i dont  understand what you mean by `You need to add the directory to the setting that contains the file libboost_log-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib.`

Comment: Have you found the lib file? Add the directory containing it to `Additional Library Directories`

Comment: @AlanBirtles where I will be finding lib file ?

Comment: Somewhere in the packages directory i guess? I've never used nuget

Comment: @AlanBirtles its really confusing can you write answer in whatever way you know how to resolve this issue step by step.

Comment: Sorry I've given you all the help I can, maybe take a look in the nuget documentation or tutorials for more info?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333290/fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-libboost-log-vc141-mt-gd-1-64-lib?noredirect=1&lq=1 help?

Comment: @IanGralinski it has some stage folder i dont see any such folder

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same mistake following the instructions on the following page:

[GETTING STARTED QUICKLY WITH C++ LOGGING](https://www.scalyr.com/blog/getting-started-quickly-c++-logging)

As your [LINK Error 1104](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104?view=msvc-160) is indicating, I guess you are using Visual Studio 2019 with platform toolset `v142`, as seen in the image:

[image]

In this case, you have to install the boost libraries for platform `v142` instead of `v141`:

```
PM> Install-Package boost
PM> Install-Package boost_date_time-vc142
PM> Install-Package boost_filesystem-vc142
PM> Install-Package boost_log-vc142
PM> Install-Package boost_system-vc142
PM> Install-Package boost_thread-vc142
PM> Install-Package boost_chrono-vc142
PM> Install-Package boost_log_setup-vc142
PM> Install-Package boost_chrono-vc142
PM> Install-Package boost_atomic-vc142
```